# Aptana Studio 3 change working dir for rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, aptana

I have an existing rails project and I am trying to use Aptana Studio 3 to debug it.

I am having the following problem:  The project was created with a non standard directory structure so that a lot of the folders that you would expect to be under project_home are under project_home/webapp, so instead of the server script being in project_home/script it is in project_home/webapp/script.  Likewise the app test etc.. folders are under webapp.

I have imported this project into Aptana but it fails to launch script/server when I try to debug it.  And this is because it is using project_home as the working dir instead of project_home/webapp.  I can't find anyway in Aptana to change the working dir for this project.  I've tried changing the working dir for the terminal and that has no effect.

Is there any way to change the working directory for a project in Aptana?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open Navigator view with Window -> Show View -> Other -> General -> Navigator.
In this window you can (for open projects) right click and select 'Move'. Change the location and click ok.

Changing the default location for all projects to start with can be done as well, see this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20858408/change-aptana-studio-3-default-project-setting